# Maximum of $\frac{\Gamma(x_1 + \dotsb + x_n)}{\Gamma(x_1)\dotsb \Gamma(x_n)} q_1^{x_1} \dotsb q_n^{x_n}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

What are stationary points , supremum and/or local maximums of a function
$$f_{i, q_1\dotsc, q_n} \colon (x_1, \dotsc, x_n) \mapsto \frac{\Gamma(x_1 + \dotsb + x_n)}{\Gamma(x_1)\dotsb \Gamma(x_n)} q_1^{x_1} \dotsb q_n^{x_n},$$over such real $x_j$ , that $1 \leq x_j  \leq i$  and $x_1 + \dotsb + x_n = i$ for some integer $i$ and some  $0 \leq q_j \leq 1$, $q_1 + \dotsb + q_n \leq 1$ (for each $j \in \{1, \dotsc, n\}$)?

The function is an extension of the probability mass function for multinomial distribution. My intuition tells me that the maximum should occur in $\frac{i}{Q}(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$, where $Q = q_1 + \dotsb + q_n$. (Since that is sometimes true in discrete case). I tried to derive the function, but I don't know how to calculate stationary points,

Comment: What is $Q$?....

Comment: Sory, typo. $Q = q_1+ \dotsb + q_n$.

Comment: Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: @BenjaminWang i could not get anything nice from that. Partia derivatives of lagrange function are not pleasant.